# undefined new_http_archive in bazel 0.29.1

Tags: bazel

I'm new in Bazel tool.
When I build an existing Bazel workspace, an error shows as follows:

> name 'new_http_archive' is not defined .

It seems this rule is deprecated in the latest version of Bazel, are there any equivalent code in Bazel 0.29.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new_http_archive` has been merged into the Starlark `http_archive` rule.

Add the following into your `WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
```

Then, you can use the `build_file` or `build_file_content` attributes directly in `http_archive` to make it behave like the old `new_http_archive` rule.

```
http_archive(
    name = "...",
    build_file = "some/repo.BUILD",
)
```